# does eight queens backtracking solution require any sorting at all?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, backtracking, n-queens

Hi I have just sat my final year programming exam, I was asked the question:
what sorting and searching algorithms are used to solve  the 8 queens problem.

Correct me if I am wrong but there is no sorting at all... 
I understand that there is a basic level of searching needed when placing the queen and during backtracking, but where does sorting come into this? if at all?

Below is what I have been looking at and just cant see it.

```
public class Queens
{
int[] positions;
int counter = 0;
boolean isFinished = false;

public Queens()
{
  positions = new int[8];
  placeQueens(0);
}

public boolean canPlaceQueen(int row, int column)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
     if (positions[i] == column || (i - row)== (positions[i]-column) || (i-row)== (column - positions[i]))
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}

public void placeQueens(int row)
{
  counter++;
  printQueens();
  for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
  {
     if (canPlaceQueen(row, column))
     {
        positions[row] = column;
        if (row == 8-1)
        {
           System.out.println("FINAL " +counter);
           isFinished = true;
           printQueens();
        }
        else if(!isFinished)
        {
           placeQueens(row+1);
        }
     }
  }
}


public void printQueens()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j< 8; j++)
      {
         if (positions[i] == j)
         {
            System.out.print("Q ");
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.print("* ");
         }
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case you're misinterpreting what "sorting" means.  In order for backtracking to work you need to be analyzing positions in some sort of predictable ordering.  If your algorithm is not analyzing positions in a set order, then when you "prune" a set of positions, you may have pruned a valid position.  Without this "ordering" or tree like structure of positions backtracking does not work.  You do not, however, need to pre-sort a set of positions or anything like that.  This would, in fact, defeat the purpose of backtracking.

The idea is that, some combination of positions never even have to be built.  Once a conflict is found ALL iterations involving that combination are no longer even considered.  It is the ordering in which these combinations are built that is a concern, not sorting them ahead of time.  All combinations must be built and considered in proper oder.  This allows u to know when we give up on a "branch" that all combinations built on this branch would have been equally(or even worse) incorrect as the option we just rejected, otherwise you can "over prune" your result set, and miss a proper combination.  But no NlogN sorting algorithms are required.  At least not in the example of the n-queens problem.  In fact, if you pre-built all positions and sorted them, you are completely ignoring the dynamic programming elements that allow us to speed up the computation of this problem considerably.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: I'm not OP, but I don't know if I agree. If I understand your comment correctly, you are arguing that ordering is a form of sorting. I think ordering is a prerequisite for sorting. For instance, if you implement some equality interface or write a comparator or whatever, you are expected to implement a `total ordering` on the type/class/whatever. But having an ordering does not mean you have sorted anything...

Comment: Thank you ChrisCM so does that mean asking what sorting algorithm to use to programmatically produce a solution to the 8 queens problem is a valid questions in your eyes?

Comment: also is it even valid asking what searching algorithm to use?

Comment: @OP: The positions analyzed in an N-queens problem could potentially be viewed as a sorted heap of positions, invalid portions of this tree end up getting pruned, and never considered, but if they had been built, the order they had been built in would have been predictable.

Comment: @ROLIU: But having an ordering does not mean you have sorted anything...  This is precisely my point.  How would you sort "positions on a chess board".  You can't, or at least not in a way that helps speed up computation of this problem.  However, you can build positions of queens on a board in an order that allows you prune a "limb" on a tree, so that you know all positions on this limb were not acceptable solutions.  My argument is that, whoever asked this question should have used the word "ordering" not sorting.  As sorting in the context of this question is invalid and not helpful.

Comment: @roliu: It doesn't lead to a sorting algorithm, and shouldn't.  I have provided explanation for why a sorting algorithm isn't used, unnecessary, and would actually slow things down.  While trying to validate the wording of the question.

Comment: @ChrisCM Then I would suggest rewording the answer. As is you have "I think in this case you're misinterpreting what 'sorting' means", you've sort of implied that the question is valid and the OP was confused.

Comment: Thank you so much ChrisCM, do you mind me presenting this to my tutor with the rest of my group to explain why we felt the exam was unfair and contained invalid questions. We was all so mad when we got out as this and searching in the 8 queens was over 30% of our exam mark.

Comment: @roliu: My argument is that the question is valid, and the OP was misunderstanding.  He seems to understand my point just fine.

Comment: @OP: I would recommend taking some factual backup besides the "guy on stackoverflow said..." but you can do as you wish.  In my opinion, it is likely that the professor uses some "coloquial" type verbage, and that if I were attending his classes I may feel that this interpretation should have been clear.

Comment: While I agree that on an exam it's always beneficial to you to try an answer a question as well as you can, it's also always the responsibility of the professor to try and ask a clear question. I am pretty confused as to how you can justify the professor asking a vague question like this. I would only be able to justify students at least writing something reasonable down. But to each his own...

Comment: @roliu: I agree, but if a professor had lectured and presented this question in this way throughout, it is up to the student to understand this.  I leave the interpretation of this line up to the OP.

Comment: My professor spent 45 min trying to get a JOptionPane windows to close from within a loop and then told the student to leave it and  put it into future development discussion.. Im beginning to wonder if he even know what he was asking or if our exam was the result of some bad searching for programming problem.

Comment: Yeah, if he hadn't discussed this problem before and presented it on the exam cold turkey... I would definitely interpret the wording of the problem as vague/misleading.  I've done the grad assistant thing before, and try to give the benefit of the doubt to the exam creator, it's hard to write a good exam.  But to suggest the n-queens problem requires "sorting algorithms", in the way the rest of the programming world understands the phrase "sorting algorithms" is most definitely misleading.

Comment: Yep, start a chat here if you need anything else!